# Website authentication using Internet explorer driver

Tags: webdriver

My website requires users to login into the system. When users click on Login buton after entering username and pwd, main login window opens a new browser window and displays the homepage in it. This works absolutely fine when doing manually but when i try to run similar script using Webdriver/Java, not only authentication is failed but webdriver opens 2 browser pop up windows rather than one. What is it i am doing wrong here? I have shared my code below.

I am using internetexplorerdriver on windows 8 and IE 10 with Eclipse IDE.

public class Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    driver.get("http://cmdlhrstg04/QAWorkSpace/datlogin.asp");
    driver.findElement(By.id("vchLogin_Name")).sendKeys("xyz");
    driver.findElement(By.id("vchPassword")).sendKeys("xx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("LoginImg")).click();


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

since there is an other window opening you will need to handle the events in the new driver  window

```
//Store the current window handle
        String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

        //Perform the click operation that opens new window
             driver.findElement(By.id("LoginImg")).click();

        //Switch to new window opened
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }

        // Perform the actions on new window
      Do your homepage actions 
            //Close the new window, if that window no more required
    driver.close();

        //Switch back to original browser (first window)

        driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);


        //continue with original browser (first window) 
        }
```